# Asp.net Detailview not updating in realtime

Tags: asp.net

When I add a product category and the detailview will not update by itself. Is there anyway that I can do that?

[image: Product Category]

[image: detailview]

This is the code of adding category

```
    <div class="container "style="background-color:lavender">
        <h2>Product Category </h2>
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsViewCategory" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="CategoryId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCategory" DefaultMode="Insert" Height="83px" Width="360px" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryId" HeaderText="CategoryId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CategoryId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="Category Name" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
        <asp:CommandField CancelText="" ShowInsertButton="True" />
    </Fields>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#284775" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:DetailsView>
<br />
    </div>
```

and this is the code of my detail view

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsViewProduct" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="ProductId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceProduct" DefaultMode="Insert" Height="16px" Width="46%" OnItemInserted="InsertProduct" HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Picture">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadPicture" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="400px" CssClass="center-block" ForeColor="Black"/>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductId" HeaderText="ProductId" SortExpression="ProductId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="ProductName"/>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="ProductDescription">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductDescription") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="42px" Text='<%# Bind("ProductDescription") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400px" CssClass="center-block"></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductDescription") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="ProductCategory">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductCategory") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcePC" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProductCategory]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePC" DataTextField="CategoryName" DataValueField="CategoryId" Height="18px" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ProductCategory") %>' Width="400px" CssClass="center-block">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductCategory") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Brand" SortExpression="ProductBrand">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductBrand") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceBrand1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProductBrand]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceBrand1" DataTextField="ProductBrand" DataValueField="BrandId" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ProductBrand") %>' Width="400px" CssClass="center-block">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductBrand") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductPrice" HeaderText="Price (RM)" SortExpression="ProductPrice" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductQty" HeaderText="Stock Quantity" SortExpression="ProductQty" />
        <asp:CommandField CancelText="" ShowInsertButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: Show us some code and what you have attempted so far.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It's worth noting that deliberately circumventing the editor restrictions on post length by adding nonsense can attract downvotes, which are not entirely undeserved. If you get this warning, consider what other detail you might add, rather than giving volunteer editors more work to do `:-)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes data controls do not update automatically as they need page reload and databinding. call DataBind() method of your control in the page load event

```
DetailsViewCategory.DataBind();
```